# Flask Security: Customize Email Templates

Tags: python, flask, flask-security, flask-mail

How do you customize the email templates used in flask security without altering the source code?

Everything else I have needed such as web templates and email subjects are configurable as defined in the configuration: 
https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/configuration.html

SOLVED:
Create a directory templates/security/email 
Copy all the email templates into this folder and you can edit them.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: Create a directory templates/security/email Copy all the email templates into this folder and you can edit them.