# Flask Security - how to change default registration email message

Tags: python, flask, flask-security, flask-mail

Working with Flask-Security & able to send email when user registers but not sure how to change the default message. I thought it would be in core.py where I see

```
'SEND_REGISTER_EMAIL': True,
'EMAIL_SUBJECT_REGISTER': 'Welcome'
```

but nothing in the default messages section about register. Currently the email being sent has 'Welcome' as the subject & 'Welcome user@email.com' for the body. Am I missing something in core.py, supposed to use Flask-Mail or something else...

Comment: Solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46623087/flask-security-customize-email-templates and here https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks @gittert as you beat me to it. Ended up turning off the default & just using Flask-Mail

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask Security: Customize Email Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46623087/flask-security-customize-email-templates)